# SwiftUI Get/Set isEnabled when Styling a Tappable Non-Button Component

Tags: ios, swiftui, gesture, disable

When styling a `Button`, the custom `ButtonStyle` need only get the `isEnabled` from the environment variable as below.

**Custom Button Styling**

```
struct MyStyle: ButtonStyle {
  @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled

  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    if isEnabled {
      do enabled style
    } else {
      do disabled style
    }
}
```

I have created another style prototype for my custom control which works well, but the the `disabled(_:)` function does not seem to set the isEnabled for anything but `Button`.

I need to adjust the styling of the control based on the "enabled" state.

I have tried placing a `Button` in my custom control instead of using an `Image` and `gesture` then use a custom `ButtonStyle`, but while somewhat unpredictable and seems to only style the `Button` in the control and nothing else. However the `isEnabled` is set as expected.

I have also tried using a `Button` where the `Label` looks like the new control, but I only want the `Button` to run the action when the right side is tapped not just anywhere on the button. I am also having difficulty limiting the tappable area of a `Button`.

I thought I might override the `disable(_:)` function, but I can't figure out how to override the `View` extension's function.

While using my new `Style` and new control I can run `disable(_:)` on it and it actually disables the `gesture` on my `Image`. But does not set the `isEnabled` in the environment.

**Testing the built-in function**

```
struct ContentView: View {

  var body: some View {
    MyControl()
      .controlStyle(MyControlStyle())
      .disabled(true) <- Disables MyControl but does not set isEnabled
  }
}

struct MyControlStyle: ControlStyle {
  @Evironment(\.isEnable) var isEnabled <- Always true even if disabled is true

  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    if isEnabled {
      do enabled style
    } else {
      do disabled style
    }
}
```

**Trying to Set isEnabled Directly**

```
struct MyControl: View {
  @State var disabled = false

  func isDisabled(_ disabled: Bool) {
    self.disabled = disabled
    self.environment(\.isEnabled, !disabled)
  }

  var body: some View {
    <Make View>
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {

  var body: some View {
    MyControl()
      .controlStyle(MyControlStyle())
      .isDisabled(true)
  }
}

struct MyControlStyle: ControlStyle {
  @Evironment(\.isEnable) var isEnabled <- Always true even if disabled is true

  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    if isEnabled {
      do enabled style
    } else {
      do disabled style
    }
}
```

I have not figured out what needs to be done to get the `isEnabled` to function like a button with my custom control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered something that consistently sends the `isEnabled` to the styling struct. It's not exactly like the `ButtonStyle` where you retrieve the `isEnabled` value directly from the `@Environment` in the styling struct. Instead I placed the `@Environment(\.isEnabled) private var isEnabled` in my component and passed the `isEnabled` value as part of the `Configuration` that is sent to my styling struct.